# ZFS Rollback not including all files

Tags: zfs

I messed up and accidentally deleted a everything in a dataset of many subdirectories. Luckily I have daily snapshots and nothing had changed so I did a rollback to the most recent snapshot. After the rollback and at a glance everything seemed okay. Exploring a little deeper there are many directories that should have files, but they are empty.

If I explore the snapshot directly via the `.zfs/snapshot/auto-2024-01-03_00-00` I can see all the files are there. If it was one or two I would just copy them manually, but there are hundreds of files.

How can I get these files rolled back into place?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring a bit more and actually trying to copy some files I discovered it wasn't just the rollback that was having issues.

The empty directories themselves had some issue. I could not remove them, nor put new files in them. I couldn't even change permissions on them with sudo.

Had the thought that something could still have a lock somehow as that is the only thing I've ever seen supercede sudo from getting things done, so I rebooted my system. When it came back all the files were there as expected.

Generally I don't think of rebooting to fix problems on linux systems thus it took me awhile to think to try it, so I'll leave this here to help anyone in the future who has the same issue.